# How to create an outlined circle with centered horizontal and vertical gaps in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

Could you explain to me, how I can draw a shape like the one in the following image?

How can I cut any part of circle to get such 4 shapes with Adobe Illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

1. Create the circle shape.
2. Remove the fill.
3. Give it a stroke that is as thick as the width you want.
4. Go to <kbd>Object → Expand..</kbd> in the top horizontal menu.

   [image: Expanding circle with stroke and no fill]
5. Create a rectangle that's as thick as you want the gaps to be.
6. While you still have the rectangle selected, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the circle. Use the alignment options to center it horizontally and vertically relative to the circle shape.

   [image: Centering rectangle relative to circle]
7. Select only the rectangle. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the shape.
8. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste it in exactly the same place as the first rectangle.
9. Right click the currently selected shape (rectangle 2) and go to <kbd>Transform → Rotate..</kbd>. Enter 90° into the dialog box and press enter.

   [image: Rotating duplicated rectangle]
10. Select both rectangles and go to the pathfinder. <kbd>Merge</kbd> them.

    [image: Merging rectangles]
11. Select the newly formed cross and the outlined circle and, using the pathfinder again, select <kbd>Minus Front</kbd>.

    [image: Minusing cross from outlined circle]

    **Et Voila!**

    [image: Final desired result]

Comment: :) I did the same answer 5 sec after you :))) thus I deleted it. But nice to see we thought the same

Comment: But you don't have to perform a lot of operations for cross - just type "+" expand and resize :) I've posted as an answer - the plus creating looks elegant to me...

Answer (score 4):

If you want extremely fast solution, grab Ellipse tool and select options as on the picture:

[image]

If you want perfect solution you should use Pathfinder panel cutting the circle with a cross.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Could you explain me, in what way can I use cutting from Pathfinder? I try to incorporate it, but result is:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/MhHfo.jpg

When I Use DIVIDE from Pathfinder, please explain me this phenomenon, thanks a lot!

Comment: @komon use `Object > Expand...` or `Object > Expand Appearance` on your black-stroke, no-fill circle before you start using Pathfinder.

Answer (score 4):

I give you another answer, but there are a lot of options.

Create a circle (Elliple tool->Shift+Click+Drag) and make desired stroke (i.e. 23 points)

[image]

Next, press Object->Expand

Next grab Type tool and type "+", then press Object->expand and resize and locate the cross along the circle.

[image]

[image]

Then select all the shapes and press Minus front on pathfinder

[image]

[image]

Comment: be warned: not all `+` signs in all typefaces are perfect crosses!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it also with the scissors tool. Invoke it from the tools panel or just by pressing 'C'. With it you can click any path or shape and Illustrator will split it in two as you would do with your scissors. One good option to do that would be to draw the circle, divide with the scissors on top of the four anchor points to create the four quarters and displace them a bit far from the center to create the gaps.